# Is it possible to force an input port during debugging in MPLAB IDE v8?

Tags: pic, debugging, assembly, mplab

I am using MPLAB IDE v8 (not IDE X) to write some PIC programs ([PIC18F4321](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/39689f.pdf)) in assembly. I am using the debugging tool MPLAB SIM to debug the programs, however I am not able to force port bits  from ports like PORTB configured as input (I can only force bit ports configured as outputs). Is there anyway to do this in MPLAB, or any workaround, like using other memory locations maybe?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the stimulus function in MPLAB 8x. Copied from the v8.92 help file:

> Using Stimulus
>
> ---
>
> During simulation, the program being executed by the simulator may
> require stimuli from the outside. Stimulus is the simulation of
> hardware signals/data into the device. This stimulus could be a level
> change or a pulse to an I/O pin of a port. It could be a change to the
> values in an SFR (Special Function Register) or other data memory.
>
> In addition, stimulus may need to happen at a certain instruction
> cycle or time during the simulation. Alternately, stimulus may need to
> occur when a condition is satisfied; for example, when the execution
> of program has reached a certain instruction address during
> simulation.
>
> Basically, there are two types of stimulus:
>
> Asynchronous - A one-time change to the I/O pin or RCREG triggered by
> a firing button on the stimulus GUI within the MPLAB IDE. Synchronous
>
> - A predefined series of signal/data changes to an I/O pin, SFR or GPR (e.g., a clock cycle). To define when, what and how external stimuli
>   are to happen to a program, you would use the Stimulus Dialog tabs to
>   create both asynchronous and synchronous stimulus on a stimulus
>   workbook. Advanced users can attach and generate an SCL (Simulator
>   Control Language) file for custom stimulus needs.
>
> If you will be using multiple forms of stimulus input, you should be
> aware of input interaction (see Stimulus Input Interaction).

Comment: Ok. Although I haven't tried that, I did read something about it. I am going to try it and come back here If I find any problem. Thanks.